# How to bridge between IBM MQSeries and ActiveMQ Artemis 7.x?

Tags: ibm-mq, activemq-artemis

Has anyone succeeded in creating a bridge between IBM MQSeries (MQS) and ActiveMQ Artemis 7.x (AMQ 7) so that the later can send messages to and receive from the first? Currently I have no problem bridging between MQS 7.5 and AMQ 6.3 by deploying a camel route and MQS libraries on the broker itself. However, the same way doesn't work anymore as each route deployment requires a broker reconfiguration and restart.
Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

A few examples ship with ActiveMQ Artemis which might be helpful:

- The "inter-broker-bridge" example in the `examples/features/sub-modules/` directory. This example demonstrates how to deploy an instance of `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.bridge.impl.JMSBridgeImpl` to the broker using Spring in a web application.
- The "camel" example in the `examples/features/standard/` directory. This example demonstrates how to deploy a Camel route to the broker using Spring in a web application.

I can't speak to whether or not either of these can be updated at runtime as I've not actually attempted that. Both of these options should be able to move messages in either direction (i.e. from Artemis to MQS or from MQS to Artemis).

Another option would simply be to [run Camel standalone](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/running-camel-standalone.html) and deploy your routes there. This would give you more flexibility as it would allow you to specifically choose the hardware where the routes run as well as how many resources the Camel JVM consumes. Running Camel routes directly on the broker, while convenient, isn't a great fit because the broker is a broker and not an application server.

To be clear, ActiveMQ Artemis and IBM MQSeries are not directly compatible with each other and are not expected to be. This true for most (if not all) JMS broker implementations. The role of components like the ActiveMQ Artemis JMS bridge and integration platforms like Camel are to solve the compatibility problem by using a common API to speak to both brokers - JMS in this case. Any broker which implements JMS can be integrated using these methods.

Comment: I have tried with the first two options (inter-broker-bridge and camel on the broker) in my lab environment. It works with the use case of sending messages from Artemis to MQS 9.1. I haven't been able to send messages from the other direction from MQS 9.1. However, I have two problems. The first one is that our production is running MQS 7.5. Do you know whether this version is compatible with Artemis? The second problem is that RedHat doesn't support any of these solutions, neither with a standalone camel (which I haven't tried yet). They suggest to use camel in Fuse which we don't have yet.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your comment. I can't speak to what Red Hat does or does not support. You'd have to speak with them about that. If you're a Red Hat customer I'd recommend working directly with them on a solution to this issue.